# Outdoor light sconce got wet

Tags: electrical, water, light-fixture

The sconce is on a wall that was used extensively by mud daubers to make a mess on.  So, I got the hose and went around the windows and around the edges of the sconce, but apparently enough water splashed into it that it caused it to flicker and crackle, and then go out. It's been 24 hours, and, although the electricity was not turned off to the fixture, it's on a timer, and it has not come back on yet, which it should have.

I am wondering what I can do to fix it or if it has to be replaced.

Comment: How about a photo

Comment: As mentioned, you may have tripped a circuit breaker or a GFCI receptacle. If you give more detail about the timer (location, how it’s connected, whether it looks operational), that would help.

Comment: does the scone use any low-voltage circuitry like motion detection, dusk-to-dawn, timer, etc? If so, that could have been "fried" by the water. If it's a dumb fixture then it should dry out and work fine, provided an upstream protection device isn't tripped.